# How to create if and or parameter statement in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports

Apologies for posting a new question but I just can't think how to search for this question.

I'm creating a Crystal Report with multiple parameters and at the moment each one is connected by an ‘AND’ in the Report > Selection Formulas part of the report (not the SQL command part).
I haven’t fully authored the report and it contains lots of arrays to deal with multiple text values and wildcard searches but I think my question should be more around logic than the technical functions.

So…
Parameters are for things like product code, date range, country, batch number etc.
Currently the parameters I’m concerned with are Faults and keyword searches for complaints against products.

(Query 1) If all other parameters are set to default I can enter Fault Combination = ‘Assembly – Code’ and that gives me 17 records.

(Query 2) Entering keyword = ‘%unit%’ gives me 55 records.

The 2 parameters are connected by an AND so if I use Fault Combination = ‘Assembly – Code’ and Keyword = ‘%unit%’ then I get 12 records. If the connect the 2 queries with OR then I get 12 records.

If I compare the unique records, in excel, between query 1 & 2 then there are 60 records with Fault Combination = ‘Assembly – Code’ OR keyword = ‘%unit%.

How can write the parameter formula to get the 60 unique records with one query?

Many thanks! 
Gareth

Edit - Code Added

This is the segment i'm concerned with.  The arrays are defined earlier in the statement and the '*' & '%' parts of the query below are just to deal with the different wildcard operators between SQL and Crystal. There are a lot of other parameters but these 3 are the only ones that need the OR kind or connection. 
Hope that helps!

```
(IF      "%" LIKE array_fn2 
THEN    ((ISNULL({Command.FaultNoun})=TRUE) OR ({Command.FaultNoun} LIKE '*'))
ELSE    IF      {Command.RecordType} = 'Complaint'
        THEN    ({Command.FaultNoun} like array_fn2)
        ELSE    ((ISNULL({Command.FaultNoun})=TRUE) OR ({Command.FaultNoun} LIKE '*'))) AND

(IF      "%" LIKE array_fa2 
THEN    ((ISNULL({Command.FaultAdjective})=TRUE) OR ({Command.FaultAdjective} LIKE '*'))
ELSE    IF      {Command.RecordType} = 'Complaint'
        THEN    ({Command.FaultAdjective} like array_fa2)
        ELSE    ((ISNULL({Command.FaultAdjective})=TRUE) OR ({Command.FaultAdjective} LIKE '*'))) AND


(IF ("%" LIKE array_k2) OR ({Command.RecordType} = 'Sale')
THEN ((ISNULL({Command.ActualStatements})=TRUE) OR ({Command.ActualStatements} LIKE '*') 
OR (ISNULL({Command.ResultsAnalysis})=TRUE) OR ({Command.ResultsAnalysis} LIKE '*') 
OR (ISNULL({Command.Observation})= TRUE) OR ({Command.Observation} LIKE '*'))
ELSE
({Command.ActualStatements} like array_k2) OR
({Command.ResultsAnalysis} like array_k2) OR
({Command.Observation} like array_k2))
```

Comment: What you describe is impossible, are you sure you swapped out the `AND`?  Also check your parenthesis (whenever you mix different Boolean operators, use parenthesis).  Otherwise, we need the original queries here, as this is somewhat opaque.

Comment: Amended my original request. There is more to the query but it's all just AND X AND Y AND... and doesn't impact the bit i'm concerned with.

Comment: it is difficult to tell why `60` records are not picking.. as we don't know the linking of tables and logic.. one suggestion I would like to give is pick the query from `Crystal report` and fire it on datbase then try your combinations by changing the qury... Then you will be able to know the which part need to be changed...